how does vim get system colors for it's syntax highlighting?
I am writing a terminal text editor in c and I am trying implement syntax highlighting. To do this I am using ANSI Colors in the terminal like this
printf(“\033[0;31m”); //Set the text to the color red
printf(“Hello\n”); //Display Hello in red
printf(“\033[0m”); //Resets the text to default color

I would like to use the system colors or the terminal theme colors in my program. I was wondering if anyone has any idea how to do this?
I can't find any information on this by googling. I am using debian linux.

I don't know the answer, but vim is open source so you can download its source code and learn its secrets from that:  https://github.com/vim/vim

What do you mean  "how does vim get system colors"? What do you mean by "get system colors". A color "exists", a color is chosen, how or what do you want to "get" it?

I don't know HOW i want to get the colors, that's what I am asking. how do you get the colors from system theme and print characters to terminal with those colors. ansi colors kinda suck.

\033[0;31m doesn't actually mean "red"; it means the color in the terminal's palette that is conventionally, but not necessarily, set to red.

@chepner: Per ECMA-48, it means red.

"red" here is an abstract designation; nothing says what color will actually be used. Hopefully, it's some shade of red. Other parts of ECMA-48 provide a way to specify colors more precisely.

Vim does not get "system colors". Vim has configuration of colors, in colorscheme, that it uses to display. For example peachpuff https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/colors/peachpuff.vim#L29
The colorscheme is translated to ANSI sequences ESC[38;2;⟨r⟩;⟨g⟩;⟨b⟩m and sent. Vim does not "get" anything, except it's own configuration, that has hardcoded values of colors in hex #ffdab9. Defualt list of vim color names to hex: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/367499c5c39057bca267716d9aad20554d4d83fd/runtime/colors/lists/default.vim#L48

Set the text to the color red

The "red" color already is the red color the terminal uses. From the description, just use it, it is the color your want to use.

ok I am retarded. thanks for your help.

@jason if you haven't checked out Build Your Own Text Editor yet, it is a very good resource and tutorial for what you are doing. (and it includes syntax-highlighting)
